Higher cohomology groups for the trivial action of the reals on themselves
For a freely generated countable abelian group $A$ with the trivial action on itself ($a\cdot b = b$) the resulting cohomology groups are well-known and eventually vanish (see e.g. here). Coming from an analysis background, the following question jumps out at me:
Question: take $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ considered as a topological group, and consider the trivial action on itself. If we take continuous cochain complexes do we get a similar result? I can show that $H^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$, but the higher groups seem an altogether different task.
Observations: Continuous cochains/cocycles are necessary here, which suggests the machinery of discrete abelian groups is not applicable. Again considering the trivial action of $\mathbb{R}$ on itself, the definition via cochain complexes gives a functional equation for 1-cocycles: namely functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself satisfying $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$. This is the Cauchy functional equation and it's a non-trivial result of analysis that the only continuous solutions to this equation are $f(x) = cx$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and that without the continuity assumption there exist infinitely many other pathological solutions.
Literature: any references for this kind of material would be greatly appreciated - many of my searches on group cohomology return information only on the discrete case.
